# Overflow Scroll Stop at selected point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, overflow

I have a sidebar with a list full of thumbnails for companies. The idea is your scroll down the list and select a thumb. Once the thumb is selected it appears "active" and thus has a higher opacity and then displays that specific page.

```
<div class="main_scroll">
    <ul>
        <li class="block1"><a class="active" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Absolute" /></a></li>
        <li class="block2"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="AMT" /></a></li>
        <li class="block2"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Atlas" /></a></li>
        <li class="block2"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Bellows" /></a></li>
        <li class="block1"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Bosman" /></a></li>
        <li class="block5"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="BWT" /></a></li>
        <li class="block3"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Calorstat" /></a></li>
        <li class="block3"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Composites" /></a></li>
        <li class="block6"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Connecticut" /></a></li>
        <li class="block3"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Damar" /></a></li>
        <li class="block4"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Ermeto" /></a></li>
        <li class="block4"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Jet" /></a></li>
        <li class="block6"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Senior" /></a></li>
        <li class="block2"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Metal Bellows" /></a></li>
        <li class="block3"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Mexico" /></a></li>
        <li class="block4"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="SSP" /></a></li>
        <li class="block1"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Weston" /></a></li>
        <li class="block1"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Thermal" /></a></li>
        <li class="block1"><a class="low" href="Link here"><img src="#" height="100" width="140" alt="Weston" /></a></li>
    </ul>


</div>
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FCzVP/

My issue is that once I've clicked a thumb "Calorstat (eg)" the scroll view goes back to the top and the user can't see that "Calorstat" is full opacity or selected. This is a web app to be clear.

I am assuming I will need to use jQuery/Javascript to get this desired effect?? Any feedback would be great!

Thanks

Comment: in a tag replace `href="Javascript:void(0)"` instead of `href="#"`

Comment: The issue is that those hrefs wont be targeting "#", they will link to pages ..

Comment: @Scott: In that case control should go to that specific page, Then how you are expecting it to be on same page with highlighted thumb?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the href(attr),
so on click on href="#"  the browser search for an internal id so its go to the begining of the web page i think so :D

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, try:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //Add your codes here
});
```